# Mount an iso9660 in ubuntu:16.04 container

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I try to mount an `iso9660` in a ubuntu docker container but I get an `Unknown error -1`.

```
docker run -i -t --rm ubuntu:16.04
apt-get update
apt-get install wget
wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/releases/x86_64/alpine-virt-3.8.0-x86_64.iso
mkdir /mnt/alpine
mount -t iso9660 -o loop,offset=0 /alpine-virt-3.8.0-x86_64.iso /mnt/alpine/
```

Output:

```
mount: /mnt/alpine/: mount failed: Unknown error -1
```

The `alpine-virt-3.8.0-x86_64.iso` is here used only for test purpose.

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028795/is-it-possible-to-mount-an-iso-inside-a-docker-container

Answer (score 2):

I guess that this is a permission issue, where the container does not have sufficient privileges to perform a mount() operation.

Check the following:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

and

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Most likely you'll need:
`CAP_SYS_ADMIN` to get it working, which is extremely powerful.

Depending which OS/Distribution you are using, it might also be that SELinux is active, and being a blocker on the permission.

Depends on what your use-case is, but in general on a production system I'd recommend to go for another solution. Elevating container privileges to SYS_ADMIN level is definitely not to be considered a secure idea.
E.g. do the mount outside the container, and map the mounted folder.

Answer (score 2):

By default you cannot run mount inside a container, that could permit users to escape the container isolation (e.g. mounting the host root filesystem). You can configure the container to run with extra capabilities to allow the mount command if you trust your application as [hargut suggests](https://serverfault.com/a/928742/351549).

However, mounting the data into the container as a volume would be my preferred approach. You would download the file outside of docker and then mount it:

```
wget http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/releases/x86_64/alpine-virt-3.8.0-x86_64.iso
docker run -i -t --rm --mount type=volume,dst=/mnt/alpine,volume-driver=local,volume-opt=type=iso9660,\"volume-opt=o=loop,offset=0\",volume-opt=device=$(pwd)/alpine-virt-3.8.0-x86_64.iso ubuntu:16.04
```

You can also create a named volume with similar options passed to that command if you'd like to be able to mount this volume with a reusable name.